# Python variable named range hides range() function in terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I am using Python 2.7.3 and IPython 0.12.1 and while in terminal I initialized a variable named range. I don't won't to restart the session and I want to use the range function. I tried to set the variable to None, but then I get the following error when I try to call range():

```
range = [1,2,3]
range = None
range(0,3000,5)
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: can you post your code too

Comment: You are overriding the function with range by assigning it None and then trying to call range which is not a function object but its of NoneType which you can't call.

Comment: Have you seen this?  Can't try it out myself but might work for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599016/are-the-python-built-in-methods-available-in-an-alternative-namespace-anywhere

Comment: Thanks, del solved it and __builtin__ is great if you want to keep the variable. I will add my code as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to delete `range` variable to get built-in function back but not give it a `none`.

Like this:

```
>>> range
<built-in function range>
>>> range = 1
>>> range
1
>>> del range
>>> range
<built-in function range>
```